# Convert a column to a list in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, bigdata

I have a column that looks like this:

```
---------------------------        
|              barcodes    |
---------------------------
|["12345678", "91011121313"]|
----------------------------
```

It can be more than 2 items:

I tried converting it to a list so that I can iterate for every barcode in barcodes but I got a type error, TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable\n'.

I am converting it with

```
barcodes = df_sixty60["orderItems"][0]["barcodes"].collect()
```

It's not working

Comment: Does your dataframes have a nested structure? It's not clear where the `orderItems` and the zero comes from.

Comment: please add the schema of your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Generally you cannot collect a column, but only whole dataframes. So you have to select you column first and then do the collect.
E.g.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2),
    Row(a=3, b=4),
])

rows = df.select('a').collect()
# rows: [Row(a=1), Row(a=3)]

as_list = [r['a'] for r in rows]
# as_list: [1, 3]
```